how to check html input element for min value before form submit
I wish to perform input validation on html input elements, like min value,  before the form submit event.
( since I am implementing a workflow, and by the time submit is pressed/executed, the elements to be validated are no longer visible).
I've tried using onBlur, but it is not fired/executed if another button is pressed.
I've tried using onChange and onKeyPress but they are fired too often, for every digit entered, and I was not able to determine when the value must actually be validated. ( when entering the first digit of a multi digit number, the new value is below the min value, but there is no point in failing the validation since the user may still enter more digits in the near future. but on the other hand, not failing assumes that he will enter more digits, which is not certain, and sometimes doesn't, so not failing the validation will allow a value that is lower than the min value ).
:-)

It seems that at least in my case,
adding an onClick handler, to/at the Capture phase ,
allows intercepting click processing before the nested button click processing,
displaying an error message and setting focus , preventing propagation of the even to the button's click handler.
example code:
function handleClick(event)
{
    // skip processing of the target was not actually a button.
    if ('form' in event.target === false) return;

    // validate all elements
    for (let Index=0;Index < event.target.form.elements.length;Index++)
    {
       let IsValid = event.target.form.elements[Index].checkValidity();

       if (!IsValid)
       {
        event.target.form.elements[Index].reportValidity();

        // form is invalid - cancel submit
        event.preventDefault();  
        event.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
               
       }

    }
  }

.
.
 <form onClickCapture={(e) => handleClick(e)} >

you can also browse the specific invalidation type in event.target.form.elements[Index].validityState.
can also set your own error message using event.target.form.elements[Index].setCustomValidity(...)
